# How do I connect my AWS::EC2::DBSecurityGroup to my AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup in a VPC context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have this AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup:

```
    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties" : {
            "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access on the configured port",
            "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                "FromPort" : { "Ref" : "WebServerPort" },
                "ToPort" : { "Ref" : "WebServerPort" },
                "SourceSecurityGroupId" : { "Ref" : "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup" }
            } ]
        }
    }
```

and I have this AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup

```
    "DBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupName": { "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"} },
            "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
        }
    }
```

when I try to bring up this stack, I get:

```
Invalid security group , groupId=, groupName= sg-a381fdc6.
```

**Edit 1**: Reading a bit more suggests I need AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup to be associated with my VPC, so I change to this:

```
    "DBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupName": { "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"} },
            "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
        }
    }
```

and when I bring up the stack I get

Please see the documentation for authorizing DBSecurityGroup ingress. For VPC, EC2SecurityGroupId is required. To authorize only the source address of this request (and no other address), pass 205.251.233.35/32 as the CIDRIP parameter.

EC2SecurityGroupId is the ID of the security group, not the name of it, and that ID is assigned outside my control, so I don't know what value to put in here.

How do I connect my AWS::EC2::DBSecurityGroup to my AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup in a VPC context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your `{ "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"}` doesn't hold the id only the name. To get a hold on the **EC2SecurityGroupId** use [`Fn::GetAtt`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html).

Your template for the DBSecurityGroup should look something like this (notice how Ref have been replaced by Fn::GetAtt:

```
"DBSecurityGroup": {
"Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
"Properties": {
   "EC2VpcId"              : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
   "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "InstanceSecurityGroup", "GroupId" ] } },
   "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you RDS Security group is defined inside a VPC, you must refer to other security group by group-id, not by group name.

See
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group-rule.html

"**For VPC DB Security Groups, use EC2SecurityGroupId.** For EC2 Security Groups, use EC2SecurityGroupOwnerId and either EC2SecurityGroupName or EC2SecurityGroupId."

You can get the Security group ID by using the "Ref" function as described here 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html

So, your modified Security Group should be

`"DBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"} },
            "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
        }
    }`